# Marginal p.m.f. of two random variables with joint p.m.f. $p(x,y) = 2^{-x-y}$

Tags: probability, random-variables, marginal-distribution

Two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$, whose values are positive integers, have the joint probability mass function:

$$p(x,y) = 2^{-x-y}$$

I need to determine the *marginal probability mass functions*, which I believe to be defined as $p(x) = \sum p(x,y)$ for $y$ and $p(y) = \sum p(x,y)$ for $x$.

But there is no interval of definition, so how am I suppose to do the table or use the formula to find the marginal probability mass functions?

I think I am missing a formula but I just can't find it.

Comment: What do you mean by "no interval of definition"?

Comment: For example, 0<x<5 and 0<y<5

Comment: ok, you mean the support of the random variable $(X,Y)$ ; see my answer below.

Comment: no intervals? Read more carefully, $X$ ans $Y$ are *discrete* RVs whose *values are positive integers*. Of course there are no intervals because they take values on $\{1,2,...\}$!

Comment: Sorry I didn't phrase that correctly. I meant that in my usual exercises we would have an interval for X and Y that was "closed", so we could do the table.

Answer (score 3):

You are right for the formula of the marginal.

Since the joint probability is $$ p(x,y)= 2^{-x-y}$$
if you are not sure about the support of $(X,Y)$ (which is include in $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ from your hypothesis), use that you must have 
$$\sum_{(x,y)\in A\times B} 2^{-x-y}=P((X,Y)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})= 1$$
to determine the support of it.

Since $2^{-x-y}=2^{-x}2^{-y}$ are positive elements, we can use Fubini, so 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{(x,y)\in A\times B} 2^{-x-y}&=\sum_{x\in A}\sum_{y\in B} 2^{-x-y}\\
& = \sum_{x\in A}\sum_{y\in B}2^{-x}2^{-y} \\
& = \sum_{x\in A} 2^{-x}\sum_{y\in B}2^{-y} 
\end{align*}
Since 
$$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n} = 1  $$
It implies $A=B=\{1,2,\dots \}$

Now, using the formula you gave :
\begin{align*}
 p(x)&=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}p(x,y)\\
& =\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}2^{-x-y} \\
& =\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}2^{-x}2^{-y} \\
& =2^{-x}\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}2^{-y}=2^{-x}
\end{align*}
same method for $p(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

$X$ and $Y$ takes positive integers.

Hence

$$p(x) = \sum_{y=1}^\infty p(x,y)$$

Geometric sum might help you to solve the problem.

Similarly for $p(y)$.